# Proving $1-\cos(k)\geq\frac{2}{\pi^{2}}k^{2}$ for $k\in(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I am trying to prove the following:

$$1-\cos(k)\geq\frac{2}{\pi^{2}}k^{2}\quad\hbox{for}\quad k\in(-\pi,\pi]$$

So far, I have tried using some Maclaurin expansion arguments, but when that didn't work out (I couldn't figure out how to get the $\pi^{2}$ involved), I tried some calculus arguments.  Specifically, I set up a function as the difference of the left and right sides and tried to show that it's global min was 0, following the process of proofs I have done for bounds on sine, to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

For $k \in [-\pi,\pi]$, $$|\sin(\frac{k}{2})| \ge \frac2{\pi} |\frac{k}{2}|$$

(Using Jordan's inequality).

Then, $\sin^2(\frac{k}{2}) \ge \frac1{\pi^2}k^2$

Can you handle it from here?

See: [Jordan's inequality](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan's_inequality)

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.  I feel bad now, because the proof of Jordan's inequality was exactly the proof concerning the bound on sine that I mentioned in my original post!